# How to convert a string size 1 into Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

Just get back into coding. But came across this issue.

How do I get a 1 string into a dataframe where it sorts every five lines into a column.

The string show

```
"Jane Doe
Male-52
City- NYC
$36,000
total salary
Amy sam
Female-65
City- NYC
$38,000
total salary
.....
.....
and so on
"
```

How do I get it to be a data frame where I can put it into

```
Name     Sex age City Total Salary
Jane Doe  Male 52 NYC  36,000
Amy Sam   Female 65 NYC 38,000
......
```

My code is

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="file"]""")


data = "".join([element.text for element in elements])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
s = """Jane Doe
Male-52
City- NYC
$36,000
total salary
Amy sam
Female-65
City- NYC
$38,000
total salary"""

import re

df = pandas.DataFrame(re.findall("(\w+ \w+)\n(\w+)-(\d+)\nCity- (\w+)\n\$(.*)",s),
                      columns=["name","sex","age","city","salary"])


print(df)
```

is one way to solve this ...

Comment: i dont understand what you mean i get index 0,1,... see: https://repl.it/repls/TrustworthyProfitableEmacs

Answer (score 0):

This should work for n number of columns - you would just have to pass in appropriate column names to dataframe afterwards. You will also have to clean up the columns and delete unnecessary ones after the reshaping is done

Edited to include the entire code and output

```py
import pandas as pd

mystr = """Jane Doe
Male-52
City- NYC
$36,000
total salary
Amy sam
Female-65
City- NYC
$38,000
total salary"""

num_columns = 5
df = pd.Series(mystr.split("\n"), name="data")
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((int(df.shape[0]/num_columns), num_columns)))
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0BVK.png)

Comment: thanks but I got 'str' object has no attribute 'Series'

Comment: Could you tell me which line has the error? You have probably imported pandas using ```import pandas as pd``` right?

Comment: yes i have import pandas as pd the line that has it is df = pd.Series(mystr.split("\n"), name="data")

Comment: Added the output image and the code - Not clear if this is what you wanted